# Slideshare API - curl in php - problem get_slideshow

Tags: php, api, curl

I have a problem to download the slides I have available on the website www.slideshare.net, through the API I can not download all the slides that I have available at my own regardless of whether they are public or private. Can you help me?

```
$apikey = 'apikey'; 

$secret = 'secret'; 

$ts = time(); 

$hash = sha1($secret.$ts);

$postdata = '&api_key='.$apikey.'&ts='.$ts.'&hash='.$hash;


$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.slideshare.net/api/2/get_slideshow";); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 


$output = curl_exec($ch); 


if ($output === FALSE) {

    echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch); 

} else { 

    var_dump($output); 

} 

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: What is the output that you get?

Comment: I get such a message : string(146) Required Parameter Missing

Comment: According to the documentation (https://www.slideshare.net/developers/documentation), slideshow_id and slideshow_url are required parameters, which you do not appear to be passing. slideshow_url is only required to be set if the slideshow_id is not set.